# Print one line before the match if column is matched

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am searching for a match case in a file.

In the 3rd column, I want to look for the entry '0.000000' appearing for the first time; and then print that row as well as one row before. For that I wrote the command:

```
grep -m1 -B1 '0.000000'
```

But this command doesn't search for the match in the desired 3rd row. Instead it finds the match at any position and prints the two rows. For example below, it finds the match case in 8th column.

[image]

Comment: It is always recommended to post samples in text format, so kindly edit your post and let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` is not the right tool for this, you should use `awk` if possible. In the following example, third column is compared to the string `0.000000` and printed. Note that `{prev=$0}` block is to store the previous line in the `prev` variable from each line. `exit` is used as you only want first match.

```
awk '$3=="0.000000"{print prev RS $0 ;exit}{prev=$0}' inputfile
```